# Not able to get click events after using ComposeView inside NestedScrollView in a fragment

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am slowly migrating a screen to Jetpack compose, for this I am taking one component, lets say a horizontal list and converting it to a Composable and using ComposeView XML tag to put it inside fragment.

When I open the app, I am able to click on it, when i scroll down to a point where there is another compose view its not working,

Following is simple structure of my fragment.
Fragment

- [Views]
- [ComposeView]
- [Views]
- [ComposeView]
- [Views]

When this is visible on screen, click events work

- [Views]
- [ComposeView]
- [Views]

When i scroll to this, all compose callbacks stop working and now even if i scroll back up no touch events are working

- [Views]
- [ComposeView]
- [Views]
- [ComposeView]

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem (with my `recyclerView` containing a compose view with normal **XML** views and whenever I scroll down and interact with other views when the compose view is out of the window the compose view's click actions stop working)
my solution for the same is below :

```
setViewCompositionStrategy(ViewCompositionStrategy.DisposeOnDetachedFromWindowOrReleasedFromPool)
```

While inflating the compose, use this strategy that will help the compose dispose accordingly, and if it's not inside the recycler View you can use a simple strategy known as `DisposeOnDetachedFromWindow`
that will help to compose to determine when it has to bind again to the parent

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).